# Get column creation date?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

i am using oracle 11. I need to find when specific column was created. I know we can find out last DDL change date but first i created the column
and after some days created index on one of the column of same table . So now, I need to find when that specific column was created .
 Is there a way ?

Comment: see same question here https://community.oracle.com/thread/401308

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your audit settings if the object was being audited you may find it in audit trail. I'd suggest reading
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28337/tdpsg_auditing.htm

Or you can use LogMiner to check redo logs if you DB was running in `ARCHIVELOG` mode. But I have never used this so I'm not sure about all the requirements there.